# Laravel Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider::class Not found

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk, amazon-qldb

I want to use AWS QLDB Client using aws sdk in laravel v7
I have followed all procedures written [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php).
I'm getting this error

*Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider::class Not found*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Aws SDK PHP` does not have a provider built in, it is for vanilla `PHP`. You will need to install the `Laravel` version of it, you can find the package on [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel).

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel
```